# How to delete GitHub issues lables?

Tags: github, github-api

I create a repository on GitHub. And I wan't create a issue label Linux, but I input wrong as linux, Now, I wan't change it or delete it, what should I do?

Note: I need to delete a label from all issue not only a single issue issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it via the [REST API of GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/). How to work with lables and issues is documented in the [section *Lables* of the *REST API documentation*](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/).

You can create the new label manually or also via REST, add the new label to all affected issues and delete the old label. Doing it via the REST API might be the best way if a lot of issues must be changed.

You can also consider to script it via [Ruby](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) or [JavaScript](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) if you don't want to deal directly via the commandline with the API.

At the first glance it looks like a lot of effort, but it is worth it as you will discover a new and very helpful way to manage your repositories.